# /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument Error: ImageInspectError when start kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

Today my kubernetes 1.15 shows this error:

```
Failed to inspect image "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub:v1.0.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument
Error: ImageInspectError
```

I am tried to pull  image in my local machine:

```
~ ⌚ 10:57:02
$ docker pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub:v1.0.3
v1.0.3: Pulling from dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub
e9afc4f90ab0: Already exists
989e6b19a265: Already exists
af14b6c2f878: Already exists
5573c4b30949: Already exists
fb1a405f128d: Already exists
197b0f525c26: Already exists
f133ed18caca: Already exists
ec53837eaf93: Pull complete
24caf1aa821b: Pull complete
f2d6b0ee2469: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:43caa136d717fcca3a6aad96568c9d29745f3c3d391f29facc2bebeb9c26b5a0
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub:v1.0.3
registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub:v1.0.3
(base)
```

works fine, and I am tried to pull image in remote kubernetes cluster machine, works fine. It seems the kubernetes problem, what should I do to fix it?

[image]

This is my kubernetes version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T23:35:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.14.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.2", GitCommit:"f6278300bebbb750328ac16ee6dd3aa7d3549568", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-05T09:15:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
(base)
```

Comment: can you also add, which version of Kubernetes you are using? along with the docker runtime version of the same?
commands: `kubectl version`. and `kubectl get <NODE_NAME> -o jsonpath="{.status.nodeInfo.containerRuntimeVersion}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to stop the docker engine first, by `systemctl stop docker` for example, and manually remove the folder using `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`. then you should start the docker again with `systemctl start docker`.

reference:https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396

Answer (score 0):

In case of Kubernetes, you can simply ssh to the node and remove the image using `docker image rm <image_name>:<image_tag>` command.

For example:

```
docker image rm -f registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-illidan-superhub:v1.0.3
```